# How can I get around window's max path length limit when using os.walk?

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I'm running a python program on windows which will `os.walk` a linux file system mounted on my  windows to create a tree model for a `QTreeView`. It seems that when the path of folder exceeds 260 char length, it will be considered as a file instead of a directory, and, therefore, `os.walk` stops going inside this directory. How can I get around Window's max path length limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that `QtCore.QDir` module works normally even if the path is more than 260 characters. So I wrote my own version of os.walk function similar to the following:

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore

def myWalk(root_path):
    dir_info = QtCore.QDir(root_path)
    dirs = dir_info.entryList(filters=(QtCore.QDir.Dirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot))
    files = dir_info.entryList(filters=(QtCore.QDir.Files | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot))
    for i in dirs:
        myWalk(os.path.join(root_path, i))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Subst](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true) is one way to deal with that.

To create a virtual drive V for the path C:\User\Betty\Really\Really\Long\Path, type:

```
subst v: C:\User\Betty\Really\Really\Long\Path
```

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if it included *how* to use 'Subst' to 'deal with that.'